# Error when trying to compile C program code in C99 mode

Tags: c, macos, c99

When I'm compiling a simple program like 'hello world', I'm getting a warning at `printf` function.
Here is the error message:

```
hey.c:4:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'puts' is invalid in C99
  [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
puts("Hello World!");
^
1 warning generated.
ld: can't write output file: a.out for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: googling the warning will give you all you want

Comment: @ArjunSreedharan thats exactly what I did when I saw the question

Comment: Did you write `printf()` in your source code, or did you write `puts()` and make a typo in writing the question (where you mention `printf()`).  Since the message shows `puts()`, I rather think you wrote `puts()`, but `clang` is clever enough to replace a call like `printf("Hello World!\n");` with `puts("Hello World!");`  (and so is GCC), so it could be either.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to include stdio.h in your code . Normally the compilers allow you to use printf without the header file but they generate a warning